# Getting JsonMappingException while sending data to view

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to show DB data to my webpage.
I have made following code when GET request to the `@RequestMapping(value = "/api/binder")`.

but when get request came to this method it will fetch data (I have print on console and display well) but it doesn't map to my Java Script Ajax call, it's showing me an error.

Following is my code for to fetch data :

```
    @Autowired
    IBinderViewRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<BinderResponse> getBinders(){
        List<BinderView> binders = repository.getBinders();
        List<BinderResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        ModelMapper mapper = Mapper.getInstance();

        for(int i = 0; i < binders.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("In Loop");
            BinderResponse response = mapper.map(binders.get(i),BinderResponse.class);
            System.out.println("Data :: " + response.getBinderName());
            responses.add(response);
        }
        return responses;
    }
```

but it shows me following error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.ngl.dto.outgoing.BinderResponse["valid"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.ngl.dto.outgoing.BinderResponse["valid"])
```

Here is ajax call from knockout js :

`ajax.get('api/binder').done(function(response){ ... }`

Here `BinderView and BinderResponse` have same fields :

```
    private String binderName;
    private String binderAddress1;
```

and getter setter as well in both.
and `repository.genBinders()` method bring data from DB.

Here is insert method and works fine for me :

```
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    IWebApiResponse addBinder(@RequestBody AddBinderForm binder){
        .....
    }
```

Shall I have to put any `json annotation on my BinderResponse class ?`

I don't understand where am i wrong ?Anyone pleas guide me.

> **UPDATE :**

```
public class BinderResponse extends WebApiResponseBase {
    private String binderName;
    private String binderAddress1;

public String getBinderName() {
        return binderName;
    }

    public void setBinderName(String binderName) {
        this.binderName = binderName;
    }

    public String getBinderAddress1() {
        return binderAddress1;
    }

    public void setBinderAddress1(String binderAddress1) {
        this.binderAddress1 = binderAddress1;
    }
}
```

BinderView :

```
    public class BinderView extends BaseView {
        private String binderName;
        private String binderAddress1;
    public String getBinderName() {
            return binderName;
        }

        public void setBinderName(String binderName) {
            this.binderName = binderName;
        }

        public String getBinderAddress1() {
            return binderAddress1;
        }

        public void setBinderAddress1(String binderAddress1) {
            this.binderAddress1 = binderAddress1;
        }

}
```

In console it prints data / BinderName :

```
In Loop
Data :: ada
In Loop
Data :: tya
```

> **New Update :**

Here is **BaseView** :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseView implements IEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        if (this.id != 0 && this.id != id) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The ID must not be changed after it is set.");
        }
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and In **IEntity** :

```
public interface IEntity  extends Serializable {
    long getId();
    void setId(long id);
}
```

**WebApiResponseBase** :

```
public class WebApiResponseBase implements IWebApiResponse {

    private String _uri;

    @Override
    public String getUri() {
        return _uri == null ? "" : _uri;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUri(String uri) {
        _uri = uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look into what your `responses` contains. It seems like you have a field of `BinderResponse` called `valid` that is `null`. What is that field?

Comment: Sir there is no field like `valid` in my `BinderResponse`. I have just address detail and it's `getter / setter`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : sir when I am returning `NULL` from method then it doesn't show any error, I think there's problem of parsing or else ? will you tell me am I right or ???

Comment: Ideally, you should give us an Example `BinderResponse` (the class too) with values we can test to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sir I have updated question, see under `UPDATE` tag. Here `BinderView is for Backend data fetching and processing`, and `BinderResponse` is to send data to `view or user`, view directly never goes to user.

Comment: Ok, need more details. For starters, post the full stack trace. Then, I'd like to see what `WebApiResponseBase` and `BaseView` are.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Sir I have tried one trick and that works, I have returned the `List<BinderView> object binder` then it's working and displays data as well but here situation is that we can't return view I have to compulsory return response. Now any suggestion sir ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Sir I have updated with `New Update` tag.

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` at `WebApiResponseBase.isValid`. Have you investigated that?

Comment: Yes, and more than that, it is a valid bean property name, so Jackson will attempt to create a JSON field for it. That's what seems to be causing the NPE.

Comment: Ok let me try. and get back to you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Sir I have remove extend WebApiResponseBase from BinderResponse and now it's working. but I can't do that, can it be possible to exclude that method while returning it ? because that method is used at all where I am retrieving data so I can't remove that method from `WebApiResponseBase class`.

Comment: Look into the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : what a coincidence sir,I have used `@JsonIgnore` on isValid method and works fine. Sir that tag will not do any problem in my other code ?? or it can do some problematic.

Comment: No, that annotation is simply used by Jackson, which Spring uses with `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the support sir. I have solved my problem only because of you. Thanks again great man. If you want then can post answer..

Comment: I had the reverse case where my variable was defined as 'Double' and getters and setters were 'double'. Changing variable from 'Double' to 'double' worked for me.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Jackson, by default, serializes an object's whole inheritance hierarchy, ie. the parent class fields as well. In the case of

```
public class BinderResponse extends WebApiResponseBase {
```

it seems like

```
Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.ngl.dto.outgoing.BinderResponse["valid"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.ngl.dto.outgoing.BinderResponse["valid"])
```

Jackson tries to serialize a field called `valid` from a `getter` called `isValid` (which is a conventional bean property name). The getter method, however, seems to throw a `NullPointerException` for whatever reason.

If you want Jackson to ignore it, you can annotate the getter with `@JsonIgnore` or your class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and specify the property name, ie. `valid`.

Answer (score 24):

In my case when I used `@JsonIgnore` the exception has been gone but the problem was it couldn't receive that value from `API Request` anymore and Spring ignored it (obviously because of `@JsonIgnore`) So I investigated about the issue and figured out that the problem was the `getter` and `setter`. 
I had the `Integer` property while my `getter` was `int`. So when I changed the `getter` to `Integer` my problem solved and error's gone.

```
private Integer purchaseId;

@JsonIgnore
public int getPurchaseId() {
    return purchaseId;
}

public void setPurchaseId(int purchaseId) {
    this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
}
```

Changed to :

```
private Integer purchaseId;


public Integer getPurchaseId() {
    return purchaseId;
}

public void setPurchaseId(Integer purchaseId) {
    this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 @Column(name="createddate")  
 private Date createdDate; 

 @Transient
 private String formatedCreatedDate;  


public String getFormatedCreatedDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(this.getCreatedDate());
}
```

It throws the same exception because here may be null by calling getCreatedDate() value come so it can't format null date so keep null check here like:

Solution

```
public String getFormatedCreatedDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Date createDdate=this.getCreatedDate();
    if(createDdate!=null){
        return  dateFormat.format(createDdate);
    }
    return "-";
}
```